# Help with circle and arrows diagram with PGFPLOTS

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

I'm trying to make a plot similar to this one but I'm having a really hard time. If anyone can help me getting the details, I'll appreciate.

[image]

I thought I couldn't post questions like this, but as I've seen some questions like those asking for plots similar to xkcd's, I believe it might be OK.

My far-from-good example is here. My circle has a radius=sqrt(2), but it really doesn't matter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
height=20cm,
width=20cm,
xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
ymin=-2.5, ymax=2.5,
only marks,
axis x line=none,
axis y line=none
]

\draw (axis cs:0,0) circle[radius=1.41421356237];

% circle
\addplot [mark=*, mark size=0.3cm,color=red]
coordinates {
(-1,-1)
(1,1)
};
\addplot [mark=*, mark size=0.3cm,color=red]
coordinates {
(-1,1)
(1,-1)
};
% black arrows
\addplot [mark=none,color=black,
quiver={u={x}, v={-x},scale arrows=0.4}, ->]
coordinates {
(-1,-1)
(1,1)
};
\addplot [mark=none,color=black,
quiver={u={-x}, v={-x},scale arrows=0.4}, ->]
coordinates {
(-1,1)
(1,-1)
};
% blue arrows
\addplot [mark=none,color=blue,
quiver={u={x}, v={-x-0.5},scale arrows=0.5}, ->]
coordinates {
(-1,-1)
(1,1)
};
\addplot [mark=none,color=blue,
quiver={u={-x}, v={-x-0.5},scale arrows=0.5}, ->]
coordinates {
(-1,1)
(1,-1)
};

\addplot [mark=*, mark size=0.3cm,color=blue] coordinates {
(1.41421356237,0)
(-1.41421356237,0)
(0,1.41421356237)
(0,-1.41421356237)
(1.41421356237,0)
};

\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives me this:

[image]

Comment: Do the green and red touching arrows have the same length?

Comment: @Sigur, yes, all arrows have the same lenght.

Comment: And do you have only those circles or you want some code more flexible to works with more circles?

Comment: @Sigur, no, just those as in the picture.

Comment: Why use `pgfplots`? Such figures are better drawn using `pgf`/`tikz` or `metapost`.

Comment: @Aditya, I've never heard of metapost. I thought pgf / tikz was almost the same thing. Just thought that pgfplots was kind of a higher level language for pgf. Am I wrong?

Comment: Tikz is the higher level language for pgf. Pgfplots is for frawing data plots, not diagrams. Metapost is much older than pgf, and much better at doing calculations. Other alternatives are pstricks (which inspite of the name works with pdftex as well) and asymptote (metapost with a c-like syntax).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `pgfplots` construction, you can use an alternating style which are slightly verbose here (repetition of `->, ultra thin` etc.) Luckily the structure is easy to identify. You can furnish further according to your needs.

EDIT: Thanks to JLDiaz' color-seeing eyes, I took a stab on the green arrows. Hope it hits the right one :)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,
cnode/.style={circle,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0},
myline/.style={ultra thin,->}
]
\def\myarrowlen{5mm}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{sqrt(2)}

\node[draw,circle,minimum size=2*\myradius cm] (bigc) at (0,0) {\tiny +};

\foreach \x in {1,...,8}{
\ifodd\x\relax
    \node[cnode,fill=red] (n-\x) at (bigc.45*\x) {};
    \draw[red,myline] (n-\x)  -- ($(n-\x)!-\myarrowlen!(bigc.45*\x+45)$);
    \draw[red,myline] (n-\x)  -- ($(n-\x)! \myarrowlen!(bigc.45*\x+45)$);
\else
    \node[cnode,fill=blue] (n-\x) at (45*\x:\myradius) {};
    \draw[blue , myline] (n-\x) -- ($(n-\x)!-\myarrowlen!(bigc.45*\x+45)$);
    \draw[green, myline] (n-\x) -- ($(n-\x)! \myarrowlen!(bigc.45*\x-45)$);
    \draw[     , myline] (n-\x) -- ++({45*(\x-2)}:\myarrowlen);
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm... Colorblind here and in the comments green and red are mentioned, sorry in advance.

Comment: The green arrows are the third (the ones at -45) in the blue circles. By the way, great answer! (+1)

Comment: @JLDiaz Thank you very much for the pointer :)

Comment: Thank you! This answer is really simple. Just to add to this colorblindness stuff, the arrow pointing from the red circle to the blue circle (opposite to green) is actually brown. ;)

Comment: @percuße, your example works flawlessly in a standalone file. But when I embed it in my main document (with an `\input` command) it gives the error: "Package pgf Error: No shape named current axis is known \end{tikzpicture}". So I tried editing your code and included an empty `\being{axis} \end{axis}` and it compiles with no errors (but it draws the axis, of course). Also I noted that, despite the error, the figure is drawn in the main document. Although, as I use tikz externalize, the separate pdf file is not created. Do you know why this is hapenning?

Comment: @perr0 This example has nothing to do with pgfplots. Pgfplots is an extra package for plotting and it is build on top of TikZ/PGF. So you shouldn't mix this with `axis` environment. Pgfplots can understand TikZ syntax but TikZ don't know anything about `pgfplots` axis environment. From the error I can see that there is a dangling axis environment involved. Just copy/paste it into an article, book etc. and it should work (don't forget to copy `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` to your preamble too.

Comment: @percuße I think I found the problem. There is a `/tikz/every picture/.append style={trim axis left,trim axis right}` for picture alignment in my preamble. If I'm right, it doesn't find the axis for this picture. The error is gone when I comment this section.

Comment: @perr0 Ah yes, that's a `pgfplots` specific setting.

Comment: @percuße can you explain briefly how the node naming `(n-\x)` and positioning `(bigc.45*\x)` and `(45*\x:\myradius)` work?

Comment: @perr0 The first is something I've put just in case you need to refer to them later. Counter clockwise each node has the name `n-1`,`n-2`... the second is a node anchor mechanism `(node name.angle)` means the angle on the node shape border, on the circle for example `(bigc.180)` refers to the point on the border, left side of the node `(bigc)`. The third is the TikZ polar coordinate syntax `(angle:length)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution using metapost (I used ConTeXt, but you can use standalone metapost, or metapost embedded in LaTeX as well).

The main difference from percusse's solution is that instead of specifying the length and angle of the arrows, I calculate it based on the location of the nodes. Unlike TikZ, metapost does not provide a nice way to shorten paths, so I define a macro that does that.

```
\startMPinclusions
  vardef shorten(expr p, q, d) =
    % p = start point
    % q = end point
    % d  = distance
    newpair qq;
    qq := q - d*dir(angle(q-p));
    (p -- qq)
  enddef;
\stopMPinclusions
\starttext
\startMPpage[offset=3mm]
  newnumeric u; u := 2cm; % Radius of the circle
  newnumeric w; w := 3mm; % Radius of nodes
  newnumeric d; d := 0.25mm; % Distance between arrows

  draw fullcircle scaled (2*u);

  newpath node;
  node := fullcircle scaled w;

  % Use 10 points to avoid modular arithematic
  for i = 0 upto 10 : 
      z[i] = u*dir(45*i);
  endfor

  newpair mid_point ;
  newpair scratch_point ;
  newnumeric tangent_angle;

  for i = 1 upto 8 :
    if i mod 2 = 0 : % blue node
      % Caclulate coordinates
      mid_point := 0.5[z[i], z[i-1]];
      scratch_point := 2*z[i] - 0.5(z[i] + z[i+1]);

      % Draw arrows
      drawarrow shorten(z[i], mid_point, d) withcolor green;
      drawarrow shorten(z[i], scratch_point, d) withcolor blue;

      tangent_angle := angle(0.5[mid_point, scratch_point] - z[i]);
      scratch_point := z[i] + abs(z[i] - mid_point)*dir(tangent_angle);

      drawarrow shorten(z[i], scratch_point, d) withcolor black;

      % Draw node
      fill node shifted z[i] withcolor blue;
    else : % red node
      % Caclulate coordinates
      mid_point := 0.5[z[i], z[i+1]];
      scratch_point := 2*z[i] - mid_point ;

      % Draw arrows
      drawarrow shorten(z[i], mid_point, d) withcolor red;
      drawarrow shorten(z[i], scratch_point, d) withcolor red;

      % Draw node
      fill node shifted z[i] withcolor red;
    fi
  endfor

\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: After ConTeXt now I feel the need to learn MetaPost thanks to you. Let me finish my thesis please :P